# XPath Query Problem using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape the price field from [this website](http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=GX-033-HS) using the HTML Agility Pack.

My code is as follows;

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(String.Format(overClockersURL, componentID));
var priceContent = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"prodprice\"]");
```

I obtained the XPath query by using Firebug's "**Copy as XPath**" feature.

The problem I'm having is that **SelectSingleNode** is returning **null** - it doesn't seem to find the element specified by the query. I'm a bit stumped as to why, but I don't have much experience with XPath, so would appreciate some pointers as to what I've done wrong.

Comment: It is an irritation of mine that the HTML Agility Pack returns null when an empty collection would be better. Have you tried experimenting the the XPath and replacing the " * " with known element names, e.g. if you know that there is a div with an id of "prodprice" to replace the " * " with "div" to see if you get a different result?

Comment: Sorry, had to add spaces in the last comment to make the asterisks show up as it interpreted them as start/end of italic markers.

Comment: Hi @Colin Mackay: I tried "//span[@id='prodprice']", but same result - null is returned :S

Comment: @Oscar Mederos: That's exactly what was happening - thanks for your suggestion. If you move your comment up to an answer then I can mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When that happens, you should check if the page is being loaded correctly (you said you're through a HTTP Proxy?)

Try writing the content of `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` to a text file so you can see if the page is being loaded correctly. Maybe you're getting an error page instead of the original page.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion Oscar - it turned out that I was just receiving an error page because I wasn't explicitly specifying the proxy which is set in my system settings. After doing that (via one of the overloads of the Load method), everything worked as intended.

Answer (score 1):

If I run this code:

```
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load("http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=GX-033-HS");
    var priceContent = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"prodprice\"]");
    Console.WriteLine("price=" + priceContent.InnerHtml);
```

It outputs:

```
price=529.99
```

So it seems to be working. You can also use `//span[@id=\"prodprice\"]"` which is better as it avoids all non SPAN tags.

Comment: Hi @Simon Mourier - what version of the HTML Agility Pack are you running? I'm using the current stable release, 1.4.0.0, and running your code above results in priceContent being null for me.

Comment: @C.McAtackney - I'm running 1.3.0.0 - the one I wrote :-)

Comment: You need to get the latest version ;) I think I may have some idea what's going on though; how does HtmlWeb.Load interact with proxies? Will it use the system settings by default, or is there something extra you have to do in order to route requests through the system proxy?