# How do HtmlAgilityPack extract text from html node whose class attribute appended dynamically

Tags: html-agility-pack

Dear friends,I want to extract text `平均3.6 星` from this code segment excerpted from amazon.cn.

```
<div class="content"><ul>
<li><b>用户评分:</b>
<span class="crAvgStars" style="white-space:no-wrap;">
<span class="asinReviewsSummary" ref="dp_db_cm_cr_acr_pop_" name="B004GUSIKO">
<a>
  <span class="swSprite s_star_3_5 " title="平均3.6 星">
  <span>平均3.6 星</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

My question is span class tag value `"s_star_3_5 "` vary from different customer's rating level and appended dynamically. So I attempt to use `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(" //span[@class='swSprite']").InnerText`  or `//span[@class='swSprite s_star_3_5 ']`, but the result is an error or not what my want !

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could test your query with an [Online XPath tester](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) to find errors in your query.

Comment: thank you , I know the specific error as object reference not set instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you saving the value of `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` to a local `.html` file and see if the code you're obtaining is that code. The thing is that sometimes you start parsing a website using HtmlAgilityPack, but the very first problem is that you're not getting the valid HTML correctly. Maybe you're getting a 404 error, or a redirection, etc.

I'm suggesting this because I tested `//span[@class='swSprite s_star_3_5 ']` and worked correctly.

That was the issue in the following questions:

- [Selecting nodes that have an attribute with spaces using HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105216/selecting-nodes-that-have-an-attribute-with-spaces-using-htmlagilitypack/6147546#6147546)
- [XPath Query Problem using HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980670/xpath-query-problem-using-html-agility-pack/6045192#6045192)

If that doesn't help, post the HTML code and I'll help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(myHtml);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[starts-with(@class, 'swSprite')]");
Console.WriteLine("Text=" + node.InnerText.Trim());
```

and outputs

```
平均3.6 星
```

Note I use the XPATH [starts-with function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256174.aspx).